# Passing in false to setBlockNetworkLoads() crashes my android app

Tags: android, webkit

What is the requirement to make use of this:

```
mMessageContentView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.message_content);

mMessageContentView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
```

Everytime I set `setBlockNetworkLoads` to false. My application crashes! If I set it to `true`, it works fine but my application can't load images over the network.

Is there something I need to do before hand before I can set it to `false`?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error

Comment: @Gallal - I should of done that first! Having looked at the logs I am missing `INTERNET PERMISSION`. Oh dear!

Comment: Good that you found the solution, you should probably post it as an answer and mark it as answered so that the question does not remain unanswered.

Comment: I will add an answer, I have to wait 5 hours though since I don't have enough rep yet!

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by Gallal - I should of made use of the logs. A quick command on dos:

`adb logcat`

Showed that my application was missing the internet permission in the manifest file. So adding the following to my android manifest solved my problem:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`